# Highchart guage needles showing below data labels

Tags: javascript, highcharts

How can i bring gauge needles above the datalabels. I tried zIndex but its not working. These are the gauge options

```
gauge: {
  pivot: {
    radius: 5,
    backgroundColor: '#ea7001'
  },
  dial: {
    backgroundColor: '#ea7001',
    baseWidth: 5,
    topWidth: 5,
    baseLength: '0%', // of radius
  }
},
```

},

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c14dns2h/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're applying the `zIndex` to the wrong elements.

It's not the data labels that are showing above the needle, it's the `yAxis` labels.

The axis label `zIndex` defaults to 7 - usually the labels are outside of the plot area, and in most cases you would probably want them to show above other elements. Your case changes the expectation.

You can adjust the axis label `zIndex` here:

```
labels: {
  zIndex: 1, //<--
  step: 1,
  distance: -20,
  style: {
    "font-size": "8px"
  }
},
```

Updated fiddle:

- http://jsfiddle.net/c14dns2h/1/